# APNS Send notifications from multiple servers

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am writing an iOS application which will be sent notifications over APNS from backend servers.

Can I configure multiple servers to connect to APNS and send notifications? If so, is there a limit on the number of servers which can send notifications for a single application?

I can't find any details about this on the Apple site (e.g. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple servers (Providers) connected to the APNS to send notifications to the same application, and no, there is no limit on how many. You just have to have the same APNS certificate on all of them.

Comment: Do you know if the lack of a limit is documented anywhere? I have previously been told that there was a limit of 6 servers but the person who told me this couldn't back this up with a source.

Comment: No. I assume that if there would be a limit (I fail to see any reason there would be), it would be thoroughly documented. Especially since the docs says "You may establish multiple, parallel connections to the same gateway or to multiple gateway instances.".

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up again, but does this still work for you today? I'm concerned that Apple may have changed their minds and this is no longer the case.

Comment: @Etienne, I have the same concern. Since one machine has been maintaining a persistent connection to APNS I can no longer connect from a different machine despite using the same certificate. Is this what you are experiencing? I will investigate in more detail and possibly post an updated answer.

Comment: @s.bandara things seem to work fine for me. I can't attest for your case since I'm using a library called PushSharp to communicate with the APN and it doesn't maintain a single connection overtime. It opens new connections when needed.

Answer (score 4):

Having multiple servers (providers) works well when sending notifications, the question is how to handle the Feedback service?

One server might query the feedback service, get a list of device tokens that have been removed but some tokens might be there from a push notification send from another server.

Comment: That's a good point and one which I had to address by having a single server poll the Feedback service and expose the downloaded data to all of the servers which are sending notifications to APNS.

Comment: Thanks mchr, that's what I'm going to do.

Comment: Just to clarify, the central service which I wrote simply polled the Feedback service and cached any returned data for a few hours. This allows enough time for all of the notification servers to poll my central Feedback service and process any Feedback data which is relevant to them. It is safe to return the same Feedback data to a notification server multiple times as Feedback data is idempotent.