# Apple Push Notification Service and certificates, how does it work?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, code-signing-certificate

I am confused as to how `APNS Certificates` work. I have one paid `Apple Developer` account that I use. I downloaded the `APN Tester` which basically sends out a test notification using the APNS certificate I created. And works perfectly fine on one computer.

But then I exported my `Developer Profile` to another Mac and ran the same APNS Certificate with the tester and I get an error code saying `Error handshaking`.

Why would this work on one computer and not another with the same developer profile? I have tested XCode projects and I can run them both on either computer with the same `signing identity`.

How would this work for our server that would send out the `APNS notifications`? Would that computer need it's own developer profile to be able to send them out?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: The certificate will be sufficient. However, I found that establishing a connection from one machine will prevent another machine from connecting, although I could not go the bottom of this problem. For sure relevant for auto-scaled deployments. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3512770/1916766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a certificate is created, it is paired with a private key in your mac's keychain. When you export the certificate to another mac, export private key as well because without private key this certificate will not work.

Regarding how will it work on server, it depends on your server. If you have php server please have a look on this great [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1). For node.js you can look at [this.](https://github.com/argon/node-apn/wiki/Preparing-Certificates) Or you can search for others.